# How to turn std::initializer_list into column matrix or column vector during initialization?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have two class `my_matrix` and `my_vector`. The class `my_vector` is inherited from `my_matrix`. Also the `my_matrix` class is made of 2d `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. I want to make `my_vector`  a `column vector/column matrix` which it its basically a `nx1` matrix.

When I try to initialize a matrix by `std::initializer_list` it works fine

```
class my_matrix{
    public:
        my_matrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>> list: row(list.size(),
                                   col((*list.begin()).size()), matrix(list){}

    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<double> matrix; // I am planning to use single contiguous memory in future
    };
```

This allows me to value initialize matrix 
  `my_matrix mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};`
    Now I use matrix to create vector (mathematical)

```
    class my_vector: public Matrix{
        my_vector(std::initializer_list<double> list):Matrix({list}){}
        // my_vector(std::initializer_list<double> list)
     //:Matrix({some how I could do  {{list[0]}, {list[1]}, {list[2]}, ..}}){}

    };
```

So when I try to do `my_vector vec = {1,2,3};` It creates a `1xn` matrix but what I wanted was `nx1`.

So how can I make sure that I create a column matrix of `nx1` using the `std::initializer_list` ? Is there any other options that I should try to achieve this?

Comment: You could add a protected constructor to `my_matrix` and have it take list and a dummy parameter and in the constructor set it up correctly.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh! yeah that is a great suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did as you suggested and have the result below .. do you think I came close to your suggestion ?

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

So after Nathan's suggestion I created a new constructor as protected that would take `std::initializer<double>`   as argument in `my_matrix` class:

```
class my_matrix{
    public:
        my_matrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>> list: row(list.size(),
                                   col((*list.begin()).size()), matrix(list){}
    protected:
        my_matrix(std::initializer_list<double> list):row(list.size()), col(1){
            vec_alloc() // allocates appropriate memory for 2d vector
            int r = 0;
            // This loop creates nx1 matrix
            for(auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++){
                matrix[r][0] = *it;
                r++;
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<double> matrix; // I am planning to use single contiguous memory in future
};

class my_vector: public Matrix{
public:
    my_vector(std::initializer_list<double> list):Matrix(list){}

};
```